# Select2 language not changed

Tags: jquery-select2

I use the following code to change select2 language, but its not working and load default language

```
<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fa.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select').select2({
            dir: "rtl",
            language: "fa",
            placeholder: "any text"
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `fa.js`?

Comment: @Kenny its default language file for persian in i18n directory.